# Dropdown navigation menu overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am creating sorta a dropdown navigation menu, but only vertical where the "dropdowns" are horizontal. Problem is that I basically have 4 100x100px squares and I want the submenu to open on hover to the right. With this code I it works, except the new submenu overlaps the original square. If the position is not absolute, the submenu will expand down even though everything is floating to left. I have tried everything for hours and googled every corner but I simply cant make it work. How do I make it so that the submenu expands to the right with 5px margin to next one?

```
#nav {
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 540px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

#nav ul a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    float:left;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html" class="home">
                <img src="#" width="100" height="100" 
                onmouseover="this.src='#'" 
                onmouseout="this.src='#';">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="cloud" target="_blank">
                <img src="#" width="100" height="100"
                onmouseover="this.src='#'" 
                onmouseout="this.src='#';">
            </a>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="message" target="_blank" >
                <img src="#" width="100" height="100"
                onmouseover="this.src='#'" 
                onmouseout="this.src='#';">
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="box" target="_blank">
                <img src="#" width="100" height="100"
                onmouseover="this.src='#'" 
                onmouseout="this.src='#';">
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="#" width="100" height="100">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The extra li's are the submenu buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `#nav ul li:hover > ul`

```
left: 115px
```

Comment: Okay well that kinda works so thank you! It is a nice temporary solution but the problem in that is that it depends on your screen size. I tried also left 30% which was better but still there's different size gap depending on screen size.